# Get last updated distinct records - sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table FilesList, where rowid is identity column.

```
RowId FileId FileName  ColMatch
  1     1    file1.csv  0
  2     1    file2.csv  0
  3     1    file1.csv  1
  4     1    file2.csv  1
```

I would like to have only the last updated records, of distinct filenames, for a particular fileId (1 in this case)

Say, after an inital run of an application(C#), the records with RowId 1 & 2 are inserted into the table. After the second run, RowId 3 & 4 are inserted.

Now for the report, I would like to see only 3 & 4.

eg:

```
RowId FileId FileName  ColMatch
  3     1    file1.csv  1
  4     1    file2.csv  1
```

It is ok, if the result set does not have rowid & fileid.

How should this be done.

**EDIT:**
Let's say a FileID(1 in this case) has 3 associated files(file1,file2,file3). In that case I can do,

```
select top 3 from FilesList order by rowid desc
```

but the problem is, I dont know, how may distinct filenames could be associated with a particular FileId.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Andy, I have added some more text. Please check if it makes sense now.

Comment: Which field in your table indicates whether the records be new?  It seeks like `ColMatch` is but it is not clear.

Comment: It will be rowId, because it is an identity column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the latest record is defined by `RowId`, You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `Partition By FileName` with descending order of `RowID`. Something like this.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT RowId, FileId, FileName,ColMatch,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY FileName ORDER BY RowID DESC) rn
FROM FilesList
WHERE FileId = 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Sample Fiddle

- With duplicate [File Name](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/609ac)
- Without duplicate [File Name](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/675ac/2)

Comment: @mohan111 - Can you please expand on your comment?

Comment: @ughai for the given data i'm not getting any result.Can you please execute your query with the table data given in my answer

Comment: you should get all the data returned since your filenames are not duplicate. if you duplicate the filenames, the output is exactly same as in the question

Comment: @mohan111 - check updated answer with sample fiddles

Comment: @ughai sorry buddy i have taken the table data wrong anyway if filename is duplcate your answer is right if filename is not  duplicate mine is right ..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your problem will be solved by getting the greatest RowId for particular FileName.(Assuming the application inserts the rows sequentially.)

This will solve the purpose:

```
select * from FilesList where RowId in(select MAX(RowId) from FilesList group by (FileName))
```

You can apply filters for FileId to get the result(1 in this case):

```
select * from FilesList where RowId in(select MAX(RowId) from FilesList where FileId = '1' group by (FileName) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (RowID INT,FileId INT,Filename VARCHAR(20),Colmatch INT)
insert into @t (RowID,FileId,Filename,Colmatch)values 
(1,1,'file1.csv',0),
(2,1,'file2.csv',0),
(3,1,'file3.csv',1),
(4,1,'file4.csv',1)

;with CTE AS (Select RowID,FileId,Filename,Colmatch,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Colmatch ORDER BY (select NULL))RN from @t )
,CTE1 AS (
select MAX(RowID)RowID,FileId,MIN(Filename)Filename,MAX(Colmatch)Colmatch from cte where RN = 1
GROUP BY FileId  )
,CTE2 AS (
select MAX(RowID)RowID,FileId,MIN(Filename)Filename,MAX(Colmatch)Colmatch from cte where RN = 2 
GROUP BY FileId )

select * from CTE1
UNION ALL 
select * from CTE2
```